# Collecting data for my master thesis about gamification in Stack Overflow

Tags: data-collection

I am collecting data for my Master thesis, which aims to study how gamification motivates knowledge sharing, using Stack Overflow as an example. 
The questionnaire is very short and will take about 5 minutes of your time.

This questionnaire is anonymous, so don't worry about revealing your information. Would you be interested in answering a few questions in relation to participation and gamification in stack Overflow? I've attached the survey below and would appreciate your help.

https://surveyhero.com/c/e94ee2db

Comment: I participated in your survey. Good luck with your thesis.

Comment: So nice of you, thank you very much :)